# How to convert cstring to NSString and NSString to cstring?

Tags: c, objective-c

Lets say i have the following cstring

```
char array[1000];
```

How i can convert it to NSString and vice verse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apple's Developer Reference has a [good article](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html) on this subject. Basically, you will do something like this:

```
NSString *stringFromUTFString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:utf8String];
```

if the string is UTF8 encoded. Otherwise, you can use [`initWithCString:encoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithCString:encoding:) with which you can specify the encoding.

Here is a [list of available string encodings](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJJAICE).