# Convert char to NSString

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert from char* to NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325993/convert-from-char-to-nsstring)

I have `char myChar = 'r'`

How do I convert it to a `NSString`?

```
NSString* string = @"r";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert from char* to NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325993/) and [Convert char to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134663/) and [How to convert C string to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481396/) and [Char * into NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104357/)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the “[Convert from char* to NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325993/convert-from-char-to-nsstring)” question.  In C-based languages, a `char*` is a string (an array of characters) while a `char` is just a single 1-byte value.  As such, the solutions are drastically different.

Comment: The correct duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134663/casting-or-converting-a-char-to-an-nsstring-in-objective-c

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
char myChar = 'r';
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , myChar];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
char myChar = 'a';
NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", myChar];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSString* string = @"r";` works fine.

If the char is  not a literal then use:

`NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , myChar];`